# Indicator Functions - Can someone check my working?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

This is a very easy question but since some of my codes aren't coming out properly I thought I should check my theory to see if everything's okay.

Say we have two values $K_{1}$ and $K_{2}$ and that we have an equation

$\phi^{*} = K_{1}\mathbb{1}_{S \geq K_{1}} + (K_{2} - K_{1})\mathbb{1}_{S \geq K_{1}}$

such that $\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{1}_{S \geq K_{i}}) = N(d)$, where $N$ is the Normal distribution, $d = \frac{(r - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)T + \log(\frac{S}{K_i})}{ \sigma\sqrt{T}}$, and $K_{i}$ is either $K_{1}$ or $K_{2}$ (From a finance point of view this can be thought of as a binary option, but that's unimportant for this question).

Now, if we have have $\mathbb{E}((\phi^{*})^{2})$ then we can write the equation above as:

$\mathbb{E}((\phi^{*})^{2}) = \mathbb{E}(K^{2}_{1}\mathbb{1}_{S\geq K_{1}} + 2K_{1}(K_{2}-K_{1})\mathbb{1}_{S\geq K_{1}}\mathbb{1}_{S\geq K_{2}} + (K_{2} - K_{1})^{2}\mathbb{1}_{S\geq K_{2}})$

The part I'm unsure about is the middle term (i.e.  $2K_{1}(K_{2}-K_{1})\mathbb{1}_{S\geq K_{1}}\mathbb{1}_{S\geq K_{2}}$), specifically, what happens with $\mathbb{1}_{S\geq K_{1}}\mathbb{1}_{S\geq K_{2}}$ in the equation? What I was thinking was that,
since $K_{2} > K_{1}$ then this means we can eliminate the term $\mathbb{1}_{S\geq K_{1}}$. However, now I'm starting to think that they may be independent and that it would be wrong to just take it out of the equation, so if anyone can clear that up for
me I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the indicator functions, just use their definition, i.e. they are equal to 1 on the event they indicate, and $0$ on its complement. Then

$$
1_{\{S\ge K_1\}}1_{\{S\ge K_2\}}=1_{\{S\ge K_1\}\cap{\{S\ge K_2\}}}=1_{\{S\ge \max\{K_1,K_2\}\}}.
$$